# Eclipse Lightning Bundle Files Open in Same Tab

Tags: lightning, eclipse

The fact that I can't find others with this issue makes me think I'm missing something simple.

In Eclipse when I have a lightning component bundle (component, controller.js, helper.js, renderer.js) and open one of these files is opens in a new tab within Eclipse.

[image: Open Component]

Then when I go to open the Controller.js (or any other bundle) file, it opens in the exact same tab...not in a new tab.

[image: Open Controller.js]

Any thoughts as to how to remedy this?

Thanks
Jason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the Lightning support is intended to work in Eclipse. If you look at the bottom of the editor, you'll see a set of tabs for the various files that make up your component, and you can switch between those files at any time by choosing a new tab. This is similar to how the XML editor works in Eclipse, where you can change between a "source" view and an "xml editor" view.

Comment: Thanks very much sfdcfox!  Your involvement in this community is very much appreciated.